# Scan bar code using raspberry pi camera module v2

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi, barcode-scanner

[How to scan barcode using Raspberry pi camera module V2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50244747/how-to-scan-barcode-using-raspberry-pi-camera-module-v2?noredirect=1#comment87517688_50244747)

This is the link to my previously asked question about barcode scanning.

To be more specific:

Hardware :
Raspberry pi 
and
Raspberry pi camera module v2 :

https://www.amazon.in/Raspberry-Camera-Board-Module-
V2/dp/B071P2S8LG/ref=sr_1_5?s=computers&ie=UTF8&qid=1525942832&sr=1-5&keywords=raspberry+pi+camera+module

I have tried to scan bar code using

1) pyzbar library
2) SimpleCV
3) OpenCV and zbar

Using Pyzbar :

```
from PIL import Image
import pyzbar.pyzbar as pyzbar

file_path = 'image.png'
with open(file_path, 'rb') as image_file:
image = Image.open(image_file)
image.load()

codes = pyzbar.decode(Image.open('image.png'))
print('QR codes: %s' % codes)
```

Using SimpleCV :

```
from SimpleCV import Color,Camera,Display

cam = Camera()  #starts the camera
display = Display() 

while(display.isNotDone()):

 img = cam.getImage() #gets image from the camera

 barcode = img.findBarcode() #finds barcode data from image
 if(barcode is not None): #if there is some data processed
   barcode = barcode[0] 
   result = str(barcode.data)
   print result #prints result of barcode in python shell
   barcode = [] #reset barcode data to empty set

 img.save(display) #shows the image on the screen
```

Using OpenCV :

https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/11/24/detecting-barcodes-images-python-opencv/

I have tried all three ways to scan barcode but none of them is working.
Using the last code, I am able to detect the barcode location in the image but cannot scan barcode.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You don't say what is actually happening.

Comment: I got an empty array while using pyzbar library to scan barcode

Comment: while using OpenCV (as given in the post),the code is working for some of the images and not for other and even if I get the location of barcode, I don't know how to retrieve its value.

Comment: Here is the [fourth way](https://github.com/dynamsoft-dbr/raspberrypi-python-barcode). Good luck :)

Comment: @yushulx,  Thanks for the solution but it works for usb webcam only and I have raspberry pi camera module V2.  Now I am able to capture image from Pi-cam and store it in the directory, is their any alternative by which bar code can be scanned using image stored in the directory?

Comment: @YashAgrawal I guess you didn't try the test.py. It's not for webcam only. It's a demo using Python barcode SDK. The USB webcam is just one option for input. Alternatively, you can input a file or use data from pi-camera.

Answer (score 0):

go through this. it should work.

```
from pyzbar.pyzbar import decode
from ftplib import FTP
import os
import numpy as np
import cv2
import time
from picamera.array import PiRGBArray
from picamera import PiCamera
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'X264')

def dec(frame):
     x=decode(frame)
     for i in x:
        (x, y, w, h) = i.rect
        cv2.rectangle(frame,(x, y),(x + w, y + h),(0, 0, 255),2)
        barcodeData = i.data.decode("utf-8")
        barcodeType = i.type
        return(barcodeData,barcodeType,1)
     return('','',0)

camera=PiCamera()
camera.resolution=(1296,730)
camera.framerate=20
rawCapture=PiRGBArray(camera)
time.sleep(0.1)
cv2.namedWindow("Image",cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)

for frame in camera.capture_continuous(rawCapture,format="bgr",use_video_port=True):
    image=frame.array
    x,y,p=dec(image)
    cv2.imshow("Image",image)
    print(x)
    print(y)

    if cv2.waitKey(2) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                break
    rawCapture.truncate(0)


        #cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Thanks for your suggestion. Please make sure that you write a bit of explanatory text to the source code, relating it to the question. Also: Did you write the code yourself? If not, where did you find it? Maybe add links to related questions or resources as well.